# How do I find the first element of intersection of a string from a list?

Tags: python

For example, I want to get `","` printed given the following string and list because it's the first character of the string that appears in my list of characters.

```
my_list = [',', '.', ';', ':']
my_string = "Hello world, I am a programmer."
```

The whole intersection list would be `','` and `'.'` with `','` being the first and therefore what I want to print

I've tried the following code, but is there a shorter way to do it?

```
my_list = [',', '.', ';', ':']
my_string = "Hello world, I am a programmer."

my_set = set(my_string).intersection(my_list)
my_list2 = [my_string.find(i) for i in my_set]
my_list2.sort()
num1 = my_list2[0]
print(my_string[num1])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean , and .

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to make it easier to undestand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to find the first character that appears in the string. With the character options being what you specify. If this is the case could you do something like this?

```py
my_chars = [',', '.', ';', ':']
my_string = "Hello world, I am a programmer."

for char in my_string:
    if char in my_chars:
        print(char)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next`:

```py
my_set = {',', '.', ';', ':'}
my_string = "Hello world, I am a programmer."

output = next((x for x in my_string if x in my_set), '')
print(output) # ,
```

If there are no common characters, it returns `''` (an empty string).